# error: The non-nullable variable 'hasilScan' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

error: The non-nullable variable 'hasilScan' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_variable at [aplikasi_scan_plat_nomor] lib\screen\home.dart:19)

static String hasilScan;

Comment: What is this question supposed to mean? Are you facing such an issue and need help? You are trying to provide a tutorial on how to solve such issues? Please make your question clear about what you need help with with some sample code if applicable

Answer (score 0):

Make it nullable or give it an initial value, like

```
static String? hasilScan;
```

or

```
static String hasilScan = '';
```